# Getting "Invalid address" error on gunicorn bind with my server ip . i am trying this within the docker

Tags: django, nginx, docker, docker-compose, gunicorn

Getting "Invalid address" error on gunicorn bind with my server ip . i am trying this within the docker .
[[docker-compose.yml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91QMq.png)[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2Zjl.png)[nginx configuration file]

Comment: Could you try to remove ```-b 139.59.34.99:8000```?

Comment: i have tried with -b 0.0.0.0:8000 but its not serving at 139.59.34.99:8000(which is my server ip)

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#/ipv4address-ipv6address Can you try to specify a static IP address for containers?

Comment: please check the "docker-compose.yml" attachment(the screenshot which i have added) . where i need to specify the IP ?

Comment: your container shouldn't have any knowledge about server where it's running, especially it's IP address - you should bind gunicorn to 0.0.0.0:8000, then proxy pass to it in your nginx config. Could you paste your nginx config here?

Comment: @Matthew my nginx configuration:          upstream web {
  ip_hash;
  server 139.59.34.99:8000;
}

server {

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://139.59.34.99:8000/;
    }
    listen 8001;
    server_name 139.59.34.99:8000;
}

Comment: does nginx has to know external IP of your server? Couldn't you use `127.0.0.1` here?

Comment: @Matthew yes has to know external ip . it won't work with 127.0.0.1 .